# How to get rid of suffixes from several shapefiles in a folder

Tags: python

I have several shapefiles in a folder, each suffixed by `_LINES` or `_AREAS`.

I would like to get rid of these suffixes

```
California_Aqueduct_LINES.shp --> California_Aqueduct.shp
California_Aqueduct_LINES.dbf --> California_Aqueduct.dbf
California_Aqueduct_LINES.prj --> California_Aqueduct.prj
California_Aqueduct_LINES.shx--> California_Aqueduct.shx
Subdivision_AREAS.dbf --> Subdivision.dbf
Subdivision_AREAS.prj --> Subdivision.prj
Subdivision_AREAS.SHP --> Subdivision.SHP    
Subdivision_AREAS.shx --> Subdivision.shx
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: From the tag it looks like you're working with python, so why don't you show us your code so far and where you are having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I've put together in ArcPY

```
import os, sys, arcpy

InFolder = sys.argv[1] # make this a hard set path if you like

arcpy.env.workspace = InFolder
CapitalKeywordsToRemove = ["_AREAS","_LINES"]# MUST BE CAPITALS

DS_List = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp","ALL") # Get a list of the feature classes (shapefiles)
for ThisDS in DS_List:
    NewName = ThisDS # set the new name to the old name

    # replace key words, searching is case sensitive but I'm trying not to change the case
    # of the name so the new name is put together from the original name with searching in
    # upper case, use as many key words as you like

    for CapKeyWord in CapitalKeywordsToRemove:
        if CapKeyWord in NewName.upper():
            # remove the instance of CapKeyWord without changing the case
            NewName = NewName[0:NewName.upper().find(CapKeyWord)] + NewName[NewName.upper().find(CapKeyWord) + len(CapKeyWord):]

    if NewName != ThisDS:
        if not arcpy.Exists(NewName):
            arcpy.AddMessage("Renaming " + ThisDS + " to " + NewName)
            arcpy.Rename_management(ThisDS , NewName)
        else:
            arcpy.AddWarning("Cannot rename, " + NewName + " already exists")
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Retaining " + ThisDS)
```

If you don't have arcpy let me know and I'll change it to just straight python... there's a bit more to it but it's not difficult.

Comment: Thanks Michael!!....can you please take a look into this one as well.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986206/transformation-of-string-column

Comment: Yeah i did Michael...Thx again

Comment: Can u plz take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986206/transformation-of-string-column

Answer (score 2):

Can i do this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

ls = ['California_Aqueduct_LINES.shp',
      'Subdivision_AREAS.dbf',
      'Subdivision_AREAS.SHP']

truncate = set(['LINES', 'AREAS'])
for p in [x.split('_') for x in ls]:
    pre, suf = p[-1].split('.')
    if pre in truncate:
        print '_'.join(p[:-1]) + '.' + suf
    else:
        print '_'.join(p[:-1]) + p[-1]
```

Output:

```
California_Aqueduct.shp
Subdivision.dbf
Subdivision.SHP
```